# jQuery .change not working in WooCommerce

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to do something very simple. If you go to http://cutecuttingboards.com/product/apple/, I simply want to hide the "From:" price after the user choose a size in the drop down menu. I am trying the code below, which is working fine in Fiddle but not on the live site:

```
jQuery('#size').on('change', function(){
    jQuery('p.price').hide();
    });
```

Here is the fiddle with unformatted code: http://jsfiddle.net/anneber/U2Mat/

Any help is much appreciated!
Anne

Comment: Any console errors? Which browser are you testing this in?

Comment: Do you want to hide just the "From:" text?

Comment: I looked into your site, there is no `.change()` method called in your JS. Also, you do not have to wrap each block of your code in `(function($) { $(window).load(function(){...}); })(jQuery);` Just do it once is good enough.

Comment: what is the name of your js file on your site?

Comment: @AbhinavRanjan - no console errors. Trying Chrome & Firefox.

Comment: @RahilWazir - No, trying to hid the entire line.

Comment: @Terry - I am actually calling .on('change', function(), sorry about that. Tried .change() as well with no luck.

Comment: @Learning the file name is cutecutb.js

Answer (score 5):

i know it's kind of late but.. in case someone else is having the same problem, this should do the trick:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).on("change", ".variations #size", function() {
        $('p.price').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked. However... why does it happen? I'm still learning JS and I'd like to understand the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

If I copy/paste your code above into web inspector and then change the selection it works, so most likely, the code is either not in the page, not being run, or being run before the related elements have been loaded into the DOM.

Comment: Thanks - I tried moving the script all over the place to fire it after absolutely everything is loaded, but just can't get the thing to work.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your `cutecutb.js` file the `Unterminated comment`. i.e you are not terminating the comment

[image]

There is no **"*/"** sign.

**EDIT :**

Now another reason in `add-to-cart-variation.min.js` there is already an onchange event of dropdown

[image]

You can see you "#size" element is inside ".variations" class

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I fixed this, but didn't solve the original issue unfortunately.

Comment: Probably now you can put a breakpoint there and check whether that code is executing or not.

Comment: @AbhinavRanjan I tried that and it looks like it is loading. If I pull out the .hide() code and don't wrap it in the on.change function, the element is hidden.

Comment: @AnneSchmidt there is no problem in event binding. its just you haven't checked your code fully.Its really tough to debug bug like this. hope this will resolve the issue.

Comment: Could be some problem with selector you are using while binding.

Comment: @Learning is correct the event is propagating and it is handled by top level handler in add-to-cart-variation.min.js
Now best way to solve it may be to change your code in that event handler or add an inline handler with the select element.

Comment: If I run this jQuery('#size').on('change', function(){
    jQuery('p[itemprop="price"]').hide();
    }); in console after the page loads, it works as expected.

Comment: Yes, but how are you going to handle that in your scripts because this is temporary?

Comment: @AnneSchmidt, if you solved your problem with the help of my suggestions please mark this as answer.